# Regular expressions to remove content in a JSON file. using BBEdit

Tags: json, grep, expression, bbedit

I am trying to get rid of a load of content in a JSON file to have it prepped for translation using BBEdit.

a Line looks like this:

```
"ribbonText1" : "The text that needs to be translated",
```

I would like to remove everything so it ends up like this:

```
The text that needs to be translated
```

Any help greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Never use regex to parse something like JSON, XML or whatever

Answer (score 0):

First regexp to select a sting, regexps in `sub` to remove everything but text.

```
$ cat r.sh
awk '
/"ribbonText1"[ \t]*:/ {
    sub(/^[^:]*:/, "")
    sub(/^[^"]*"/, "")
    sub(/"[^"]*$/, "")
    print
}
' "$@"
```

Usage

```
$ sh r.sh file
The text that needs to be translated
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the example shown is part of a JSON object and the key names will vary, something like this...

```json
{
  "ribbonText1" : "The text that needs to be translated",
  "ribbonText2" : "The text that needs to be translated2",
  "ribbonText3" : "The text that needs to be translated3",
  "ribbonText4" : "The text that needs to be translated4",
  "ribbonText5" : "The text that needs to be translated5",
  "ribbonText6" : "The text that needs to be translated6"
}
```

This regex in BBEdit should do the trick:

Find: `^\s?[^:]+:\s?"([^"]+)",?$`
Replace: `\1`

As Twometer notes in a comment though, this is fragile. I'd be inclined to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for this.

`cat foo.json | jq '.[]'`